# C#, WinForms Drawing data stored in an ArrayList. Is it a good idea?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, arraylist

In my case I have 2D ArrayList full of objects that have data which is used when drawing horizontal lines, vertical lines and filled rectangles. In different cases the amount of objects is different and the image has a different amount of drawn lines and rectangles. But the image needs to be redrawn sometimes. The more stuff there is to redraw, the stronger the flashes on the screen (I hope you can figure out what I mean with "flashes").

I have already tried double buffering, but I don't think I'm doing it right- the type of the flashes only changes... But that's not the current case.

I have read that it's easy to add and remove elements (no matter the type) anywhere from the ArrayList, but the access to them is hard. I have also read that the List performs better that the ArrayList (does that mean that the program will require less resources fro the computer?), but it's only easy to add and remove elements from the end. But I'm not sure if the Array's performance is the fastest. And this is making me think that the flashes can become weaker if I change the ArrayList with an Array or List.

It won't be a problem in my case because all the elements that I store in the ArrayList are form the same class.

My question is: Can I weaken the flashes if I replace the ArrayList with an Array or List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, two problems here. The ArrayList vs. List question has no effect on "flashing", since the difference in performance is small. If your list items are all of the same type or if they all derive from a common base type other than `object` or if they all implement a common interface, then `List<T>` is the better choice. This is because less castings or even boxings/unboxings are involved. In addition, it will be easier to access your items.

Flashing: Do all your drawing in a paint-event method (of your form or of some control). Then call the `Invalidate` method of this form or control. Don't draw "directly". As an improvement, you can pass a rectangle structure to Invalidate, telling which part has to be redrawn. In the paint method, you can then check e.ClipRectangle, which tells you which part has to be redrawn. This gives you the opportunity to make some improvements here. However, be aware of the fact, that the Windows OS itself can trigger an Invalidate, which results in arbitrary ClipRectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing drawing performance with reading from ArrayList performance, you can't solve flickering problem by using another data container. So, alternative container of ArrayList is not the answer.  You need to use some other methods like;

- Using `SDL`, `DirectX`, `OpenGL` like graphics library.
- Drawing to a bitmap buffer and showing the bitmap after it is completed (similar to double buffering but sometimes it works better).
- Subclassing some components and overriding some methods like background drawing.

There are even more methods but the answer of your question is definitely not much to do with ArrayList.

Comment: In some cases the objects' quantity is not just 2x2 or 4x3, but 10x10 and a lot more... (With NxM I mean N Arrays with M elements.) And the rectangles require more time for drawing. With "weakening the flashes" I didn't mean "stopping the flashes", I meant how to make the drawing faster. And yeah, I know that I have to work on the double buffering in order to fix the problem. But if make the drawing faster (the double buffering will become faster after that), the app will become faster too. And that's one of the things belonging to the "Have to do" list.

Comment: I always supported writing better optimized codes, performance change is noticable or not. But in your case, in 1000x1000 iterations you will gain about 10-50 miliseconds. Think about how long would it take to draw 1000000 rectangles comparing to 10-50 miliseconds. (see here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/unboxing). These results for int types so, I assumed it can take up to 5 times more with other types and reduced the iterations by 100 times. So, we all know drawing 1000000 rectangles and similar objects will take a high amount of time. IMHO, performance gain won't be much higher than %0.1.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`, just to get rid of the unnecessary casting when you read objects from the list. However, the performance gain from that is so small compared to drawing graphics that it won't have any noticable effect on your update problem.

You could consider drawing your graphics to a bitmap, then draw the bitmap when you need to update the screen.

---

A `List<T>` and an `ArrayList` behave the same when it comes to adding and removing elements; it's cheap to add or remove elements at the end of the list, but more expensive to insert or remove elements at the beginning of the list.

An array is the fastest of the lists, and both `List<T>` and `ArrayList` uses arrays to store its elements internally. However, you can't resize an array so you might still want to use a `List<T>` as it does the work of allocating arrays as needed and keeps track of how much of the array is used.

Comment: `List<T>` is much faster for value types.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the "flashes", you need to enable double-buffering.

You should not use ArrayList because it encourages mistakes and/or poor design.
You should not have lists that contain multiple types of objects.

Instead, you should use `List<T>`, perhaps with a polymorphic base class.